# Robot Framework - click on the button only once

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I would like to inform, how can I set that the button will be pressed just once (the first round of test).

I do DDT and it runs 10times. There are 2 buttons, just START button can be pressed just once (at the beginning). But I enter it into keywords -> now , the start button is pressed each round, so the tests failed. See picture below.

Any idea?

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     DataDriver Testing with Excel
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           DataDriver  challenge.xlsx  sheet_name=Sheet1
Suite Setup       Open Browser  ${URL}   
Test Template     Entry data
Suite Teardown    Close Browser



*** Variables ***

#webApp link
${URL}            <URL>

#find elements
${first_name_element}      xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelFirstName"]
${last_name_element}       xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelLastName"]
${company_name_element}    xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelCompanyName"]
${address_element}         xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelAddress"]
${phone_number_element}    xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelPhone"]
${email_element}           xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelEmail"]
${role_element}            xpath://input[@ng-reflect-name="labelRole"]
#${congratulation_element}  xpath://

#buttons
${start}                 xpath://button[text()="Start"]
${submit}                xpath://input[@type="submit"]

*** Test Cases ***

    
Verify All Data From Excel
     
    Click Button  ${start}

    ${First_Name}  ${Last_Name }  ${Company_Name}  ${Role_in_Company}  ${Address}  ${Email}  ${Phone_Number}

    #Element Should Contain  ${congratulation_element}  100%

*** Keywords ***
Entry data 
    [Arguments]  ${First_Name}  ${Last_Name }  ${Company_Name}  ${Role_in_Company}  ${Address}  ${Email}  ${Phone_Number}
    #Log To Console    ${First_Name} : ${Last_Name } : ${Company_Name} : ${Role_in_Company} : ${Address} : ${Email} : ${Phone_Number}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Input Text    ${first_name_element}     ${First_Name}
    Input Text    ${last_name_element}      ${Last_Name }
    Input Text    ${company_name_element}   ${Company_Name}
    Input Text    ${role_element}           ${Role_in_Company} 
    Input Text    ${address_element}        ${Address} 
    Input Text    ${email_element}          ${Email}
    Input Text    ${phone_number_element}   ${Phone_Number}
    Click Button  ${submit}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the website link?

Comment: Thank you, I have already add a whole code